# Android gradle complains about object library having multiple outputs

Tags: android, gradle, cmake, gradle6.7, object-library

With gradle 6.5 I was able to build a cmake project which has a target which depends on an object library, something like

```
add_library(mylib 
            SHARED
            code1.cc
            code2.cc
            $<TARGET_OBJECTS:objlib
           )
```

where the object library is declared using something like

```
 add_library(objlib
             OBJECT
             src1.cc
             src2.cc
            )
```

So effectively this pulls `src1.o` and `src2.o` into `mylib`. I cannot really change this (e..g put those source files directly in the `add_library` for `objlib`).

With gradle 6.7.1, gradle complains that the target `objlib` has multiple outputs, namely `src1.o` and `src2.o`:

```
CMakeLists.txt : C/C++ release|armeabi-v7a : 
   Target renderer::@bfc844598bd03e848b3c produces multiple outputs [...]/src1.o, [...]/src2.o
```

(paths edited for brevity).

I have tried to specify explicitly that I only want android to worry about the `mylib` target, by using the following in my `build.gradle`:

```
externalNativeBuild {
     cmake {
          targets "mylib"
     }
}
```

as suggested in [Gradle fails to build a CMake project with OBJECT libraries because it expects a output file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58729852), but that does not work.

Comment: Having same problem. Would love to know how to fix it without downgrading gradle version.

Comment: It's a bug in gradle https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187134648